# Extract all requests from Swagger documentation

Tags: api, curl, swagger, swagger-ui

I've been given a URL for the swagger frontend, offering the documentation for a number of POST, GET, PUT and DELETE requests and I need to extract all requests (possibly as cURL commands), without opening each of the items and manually copying the request.

How?

Comment: Could you please explain what your actual use case is, why you need the curl commands? Do you need to create automated tests for this API? Or something else? The best approach may differ depending on your use case.

Comment: @Helen I'm tasked to perform a penetration test for the API, so I just need all the request for various tests and processes. I prefer cURL because I can easily script/redirect those requests as opposed to clicking in the web frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://petstore.swagger.io/ the app is written in React and it's not possible to see the curl request before you click on the section (because it's not in HTML tree at that point). You can try to install [CJS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk) plugin for chrome and write jQuery that:

1. creates temporary textarea
2. clicks through all necessary sections, their try now button and then their execute button
3. copies `.curl` contents to the temporary textarea

After that you can simpy copy the contents of the textarea to a textfile or something.